# Create a line with no slope in C3.JS

Tags: javascript, angular, web, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to create a C3.js line chart line with no slope (with just one value) which is a percentage.
But I just can't find any way to do it and make this line part of the chart itself (so I can't show/hide it).

This is more or less what I am trying to achieve.

[image: No slope line in linear chart]

Answer (score 1):

Create a data set (`data2`) with 2 points that span the domain of the other data sets. In example line is at `260`

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xs: {
            'data1': 'x1',
            'data2': 'x2',
        },
        columns: [
            ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100],
            ['x2', 10, 100],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 230],
            ['data2', 260, 260]
        ],
        regions: {
            'data2': [{'end':100}]
        }
    }
});
```